# It all started with `protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

Tags: swift, type-erasure

I'm working on a little problem : concurrently fetch a bunch of chunks of ordered data and output it in the correct order (specifically, fetch a load of `.ts` files, pipe them through `ffmpeg` in the correct order, but that's incidental). Wanting to separate the re-ordering (deliver the fragments in sequence) and the piping (let ffmpeg do it's thing), I've written this as two objects:

```
struct Aggregator<ChunkType> {

    private var currentIdx = 0
    private var chunks: [Int:ChunkType] = [:]
    private let serializer: Serializer

    init(serializer: Serializer) where Serializer.ChunkType == ChunkType {
        // self.serializer = serializer
    }

    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Serial")

    mutating func accept(chunk:ChunkType, forIndex idx: Int) {
        // One accessor at a time
        queue.sync {
            chunks[idx] = chunk

            // Forward zero or more chunks
            while chunks[currentIdx] != nil {
                //serializer.append(chunk: chunks.removeValue(forKey: currentIdx))
                currentIdx += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
protocol Serializer {
    associatedtype ChunkType
    func append(chunk: ChunkType)
}
```

With two implementations:

```
// For capturing the output of an Aggregator<Int> to check it's working as intended
class IntArraySerializer: Serializer {
    typealias ChunkType = Int

    var allInts = [Int]()

    func append(chunk: ChunkType) {
        allInts.append(chunk)
    }
}

// For piping output through ffmpeg
class FFMPEGSerializer: Serializer {
    typealias ChunkType = Data

    private let ffmpegBin = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg"
    private let ffmpeg: Process
    private let stdin: Pipe

    init(args: [String]) throws {
        ffmpeg = Process()
        ffmpeg.launchPath = ffmpegBin
        ffmpeg.arguments = args
        stdin = Pipe()
        ffmpeg.standardInput = stdin
    }

    func append(chunk: Data) {
        stdin.fileHandleForWriting.write(chunk)
    }
}
```

The end goal being that the usage would look something like:

```
let ffmpeg = FFMPEGSerializer(["-i", "-", "-c", "copy", "-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc", "output.mp4"])
let aggregator = Aggregator(serializer: ffmpeg)
for (idx, url) in someListOfUrls.enumerated() {
    concurrentQueue.async {
        fetch(url) { data in
            aggregator.accept(chunk: data)
        }
    }
}
```

However my understanding of associated types, generics and possibly type erasure (if that is indeed the solution here) are preventing me from finalising `Aggregator`, as can be seen from the various commented lines. I've done some reading on type-erasure (e.g. [this Big Nerd Ranch article](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/breaking-down-type-erasures-in-swift/)), but I'm not grasping how or if I should try to apply it in my case.

To boil it down to one statement : I want the `ChunkType` of the `Serializer` to inform the generic type of the `Aggregator`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message is clearly stating, you cannot use the protocol `Serializer` to annotate the type of properties or parameters.

I do not understand what you mean with *type-erasure*, so I may be misunderstanding what you mean, but as far as I read your code, you can easily fix your `Aggregator` using generics:

```
//Make `S` a generic parameter constrained to `Serializer`
struct Aggregator<S: Serializer> {
    //`ChunkType` needs always to be the same type as `S.ChunkType`
    typealias ChunkType = S.ChunkType

    private var currentIdx = 0
    private var chunks: [Int: ChunkType] = [:]
    //You can use `S` as a type of properties...
    private let serializer: S

    //...or a type of parameters.
    init(serializer: S) {
        self.serializer = serializer
    }

    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Serial")

    mutating func accept(chunk: ChunkType, forIndex idx: Int) {
        // One accessor at a time
        queue.sync {
            chunks[idx] = chunk

            // Forward zero or more chunks
            while chunks[currentIdx] != nil {
                serializer.append(chunk: chunks.removeValue(forKey: currentIdx)!)
                currentIdx += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did understand the reason behind the error message, but I was going down the wrong road in my attempts to fix it. (Something I incidentally read a week or so ago had primed me to look into the protocol or the implementors of the protocol to shield the consumer of the protocol from needing to know anything beyond the protocol itself)